# Saving modified related models in django

Tags: django

I am trying to work out a couple of things with django. I am new to python and django, but have used a few different ORM's before.

Does a **save** operation on django model save modified related models (one to many)?

```
class Grid(Model):
  name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=20)
  rows = models.IntegerField(default=10)
  cols = models.IntegerField(default=10)

  def modify_cells(self):
    for c in self.cells.all():
        c.value = randrange(1000)

class Cell(Model)
  value = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
  grid = models.ForeignKey(Grid, related_name='cells')
```

So if I have a Grid, with existing cells in it, and I call modify_cells, I would expect saving that grid to save the related cells ie

```
(from within a view)
gridId = request.GET['id']
grid = get_object_or_404(models.Grid, pk=gridId)
grid.modify_cells()
grid.save()
```

However the cells are definitely not saved with the new values.

So, do I have to call save each time I modify a cell?

```
  def modify_cells(self):
    for c in self.cells.all():
        c.value = randrange(1000)
        c.save()
```

This is pretty tough on the database (I can have say a million cells), can I use some sort of **tranaction** to control this save which might create a nice bulk **update**?

Any thoughts, or help would be much appreciated.
I am using django 1.5.1. I have looked hard for doco around this, and I either cant find it, or dont understand where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic behavior**

For each model object you want to save, you must either call `save()` on it, or use the [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) methods, e.g.

```
grid.cell_set.add(cell)
```

(Of course, you could override a model's save behavior to save other models.)

**Ways to improve performance**

(1) One way or another, know that each insert will be its own SQL statement, unless you use [Model.objects.bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) (new as of 1.4).

(2) Or as you suggested, using transactions can improve performance. You could have all operations during that request happen in one transaction:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_view():
    pass
```

For more ways to use transactions, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I am not writing stupid code. I am using 1.5.1, and the documentation you pointed me at only appears in 1.6. I think I can use @transaction.commit_on_success. Is this the best way to speed up the code? I dont think I can use bluk_create as I am updating, not creating?

Comment: @Shape, I updated the answer accordingly to 1.5. And you said "can I use some sort of tranaction to control this save which might create a nice bulk insert", which made me add `bulk_create`.

Comment: My mistake, I did indeed mean 'update' (which I have changed), which I guess rules out bulk_create